# List view is not showing in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In Fragment, list view is not showing. Here is my code. Struggling to resolve this....

I am calling LeaderList.java from LeaderShip.java which is to fill the framelayout.I am calling LeaderShip.java from another fragment...

```
LeaderShip.java
===============

package com.example.listviewtest;

import java.nio.channels.GatheringByteChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LeaderShip extends Fragment {


    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    int Position ;
    int FirstTime = 1;
    //final Context context = this;
    private ListAdapter listAdapter1;
    private ListView lview;
    View convertView = null;
    View groupView;
    ImageButton imgbutt;
    Fragment Fra;
    LeaderList listAdapter;

    String[] web = {
            "Rep. Name (R) Position\n",
            "Rep. Name (R) Position\n",
            "Rep. Name (R) Position\n",
            "Rep. Name (R) Position\n",
            "Rep. Name (R) Position\n",
            "Rep. Name (R) Position\n",
            "Rep. Name (R) Position\n",
            "Rep. Name (R) Position\n",
            "Rep. Name (R) Position\n"
        } ;
        Integer[] personimage = {
                R.drawable.image1,
                R.drawable.image2,
                R.drawable.image3,
                R.drawable.image4,
                R.drawable.image5,
                R.drawable.image6,
                R.drawable.image7
        };

        Integer[] mailimage = {
                R.drawable.image1,
                R.drawable.image2,
                R.drawable.image3,
                R.drawable.image4,
                R.drawable.image5,
                R.drawable.image6,
                R.drawable.image7
        };

        Integer[] phoneimage = {
                R.drawable.image1,
                R.drawable.image2,
                R.drawable.image3,
                R.drawable.image4,
                R.drawable.image5,
                R.drawable.image6,
                R.drawable.image7
        };

        Integer[] twitterimage = {
                R.drawable.image1,
                R.drawable.image2,
                R.drawable.image3,
                R.drawable.image4,
                R.drawable.image5,
                R.drawable.image6,
                R.drawable.image7
        };

        Integer[] arrowimage = {
                R.drawable.image1,
                R.drawable.image2,
                R.drawable.image3,
                R.drawable.image4,
                R.drawable.image5,
                R.drawable.image6,
                R.drawable.image7
        };



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.outagereport, container, false);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.leaderlist, container, false);

        //prepareListData();
        listAdapter = new LeaderList(getActivity(),1,personimage,mailimage,phoneimage,twitterimage,arrowimage,web);
        lview=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.LeaderList);
        lview.setAdapter(listAdapter);


        return view;

    }


}


leaderlist.xml
==============


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LeaderFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#04B486">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"> 

      <ListView
          android:id="@+id/LeaderList"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:divider="#ffffff"
          android:dividerHeight="2dp"> 

    </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>






LeaderList.java
===============

package com.example.listviewtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class LeaderList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final int web;
    private final Integer[] expandImage;
    private final Integer[] mailImage;
    private final Integer[] phoneImage;
    private final Integer[] twitterImage;
    private final Integer[] personalImage;
    private final String [] Title;

    ImageButton imageButton;

    //private final Integer[] imageId;
    public LeaderList(Activity context,
    int web,Integer [] personalImage, Integer [] mailImage,Integer [] phoneImage,
    Integer [] twitterImage,Integer [] expandImage,String [] Title) {
    super(context,web);
    this.context = context;
    this.web = web;
    this.personalImage = personalImage;
    this.mailImage = mailImage;
    this.phoneImage = phoneImage;
    this.twitterImage = twitterImage;
    this.expandImage = expandImage;
    this.Title = Title;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.leadership, parent, false);

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ShowLeadTitle);
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.representative);
        ImageButton mailimageview = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mailimg);
        ImageButton phoneimageview = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phoneimg);
        ImageButton twitterimageview = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.twitterimg);
        ImageButton expandimageview = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrowimg);

        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        imageview.setImageResource(personalImage[position]);
        mailimageview.setImageResource(mailImage[position]);
        phoneimageview.setImageResource(phoneImage[position]);
        twitterimageview.setImageResource(twitterImage[position]);
        expandimageview.setImageResource(expandImage[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

}


leadership.xml
==============

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    >

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/searchLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/representative"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            />

    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/searchLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" >

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ShowLeadTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Rep. Name (R) Position"
            />

               <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/representLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" >

                   <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/mailimg"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                        />
                 <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/phoneimg"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                        />

                 <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/twitterimg"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                        />
                 <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/arrowimg"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                        />

            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: i'm not sure,try to override `getCount()` within your `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: Please override getcount method then it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## LeaderList.java

```
package com.example.listviewtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class LeaderList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final int web;
    private final Integer[] expandImage;
    private final Integer[] mailImage;
    private final Integer[] phoneImage;
    private final Integer[] twitterImage;
    private final Integer[] personalImage;
    private final String [] Title;

    ImageButton imageButton;

    //private final Integer[] imageId;
    public LeaderList(Activity context,
    int web,Integer [] personalImage, Integer [] mailImage,Integer [] phoneImage,
    Integer [] twitterImage,Integer [] expandImage,String [] Title) {
    super(context,web);
    this.context = context;
    this.web = web;
    this.personalImage = personalImage;
    this.mailImage = mailImage;
    this.phoneImage = phoneImage;
    this.twitterImage = twitterImage;
    this.expandImage = expandImage;
    this.Title = Title;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.leadership, parent, false);

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ShowLeadTitle);
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.representative);
        ImageButton mailimageview = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mailimg);
        ImageButton phoneimageview = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phoneimg);
        ImageButton twitterimageview = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.twitterimg);
        ImageButton expandimageview = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrowimg);

        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        imageview.setImageResource(personalImage[position]);
        mailimageview.setImageResource(mailImage[position]);
        phoneimageview.setImageResource(phoneImage[position]);
        twitterimageview.setImageResource(twitterImage[position]);
        expandimageview.setImageResource(expandImage[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

@Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Try it out and say.